# How do you grab the control that caused postback, if it is present within a ListView ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback

I am currently working on a project that involves creating a questionnaire from a list of questions in the database. I am using the ListView control with paging  to display each question and it's choice of answers. The choices are RadioButtons with autopostback enabled.

When a radiobutton is clicked and causes postback, I want to grab the text associated with the radiobutton and insert it into another database table that records the responses for each question.Since the radiobutton is inside the listview control, I'm not sure how to handle postbacks for that.I need help in finding the radiobutton that caused postback. I'm new to ASP.Net, please help me out with this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RadioButton` has a [CheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx) event that you can use to grab the text you need.

Example:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio1" runat="server"
  OnCheckedChanged="radio1_CheckedChanged" />

void radio1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string text = ((RadioButton)sender).Text;
}
```

Or you just could use the control ID:

```
void radio1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string text = radio1.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.But is there a difference in the way we handle the CheckedChanged event for controls inside a listview from controls that are outside of it ? I am asking this since I read somewhere that the FindControl method doesn't find the controls inside the listview item template. I was wondering if it's the same case with CheckedChanged.

Comment: No... `CheckedChanged` is an event that the `checkbox` control will call, it doesn't matter if it's in a listview or not, and you'll still be able cast `sender` as a checkbox. If you were handling a listview event, such as `ItemDataBound`, that's when you would have to use FindControl to find the checkbox you want.

Comment: No, the way you handle events is the same. The difference is that when a control is inside another control's template (i.e. ItemTemplate) you need to use FindControl (in this case on the ListViewItem) to access it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alessadro and @DaveZych. That worked. You guys saved my day !

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sender` argument of an event-handler. For example in the `CheckBox`' [`CheckedChanged`-event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged#Y684):

```
void Check_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var checkBox = (CheckBox) sender;
    String text = checkBox.Text;
}
```

That works with every event, you can always get a reference to the control that raised that event via `sender`.

Comment: Every time I click on a question about asp.net and either datagrids, gridviews, lists etc you can count on @Tim Schmelter has already answered it...+1